# Excel to specify the month to report the data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Using excel, is it possible to specify the month to report in a cell?

For example, excel would need to report the latest reported sales, if its available. If  the month of February sales is not available, then it will report January sales. Likewise, if March sales is available, it would report the sales in March.

How do you write this formulae in a cell in excel? If its not possible to write such a formuale, can we write a vba to do this?

Comment: Too less information. Please give more information on the layout/Snapshot of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer:

```
=IF(B12<>0,B12,IF(B11<>0,B11,IF(B10<>0,B10,IF(B9<>0,B9,IF(B8<>0,B8,IF(B7<>0,B7,IF(B6<>0,B6,IF(B5<>0,B5,IF(B4<>0,B4,IF(B3<>0,B3,IF(B2<>0,B2,IF(B1<>0,B1,0))))))))))))
```

This formulae solves the problem of picking up the latest available data.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have a list of sales entries and want the sales for the last month in the data, you could write one formula to get the latest month. If months are in A you could write: `=month(max(A1:A99999))`

Note if you have multiple years data, you need to pull the year too or get bounding dates. You can then sum sales using an array formula like assuming the result of the first action is in D1 and sales are in B: `{=sum(if(month(A1:A999999)=D1,B1:B999999,0))}`

If you have incremental updates during the month, this will return month to date data. If you need data for the last full month, you can use another array formula to get the maximum month where the date is the last day of the month.

Comment: Let me clarify. Cells a1 to a12 are months jan to dec. cells b1 to b12 are sales data. Currently, I have jan data. I would report jan sales. When feb data is available, I need to report feb data. Is it possible to write a formulae to pull out the latest data by month. Thanks for those who have looked at this and attempted to answer.

Comment: What data is reported for the months that haven't happened yet?

Answer (score 0):

If the cells for future data in B1:B12 are blank then you just need to extract the last number in B1:B12 don't you? If so then try

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B1:B12)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **OFFSET** function to select specific data based on the month.

Insert a formula to calculate the current month (or just type in the month number)

```
=MONTH(TODAY())
```

The formula to select the current months of sales data

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B1,MONTH(TODAY()),0,1,1))
```

Have a look at the help in Excel on the OFFSET function.  It can be used to select a range of data.  For example, to return data from the start of the year to the current month the formula would be:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B1,1,0,MONTH(TODAY()),1))
```

[image: Screenshot of sample worksheet]

If the current month does not contain data yet, you can test to see if a value is returned and revert to the prior month if there is no data.

```
=IF(SUM(OFFSET(B1,B16,0,1,1))=0,SUM(OFFSET(B1,B16-1,0,1,1),SUM(OFFSET(B1,B16,0,1,1))))
```